# Got error message "The caller does not have permission" when using RecognitionAudio.FromStream()

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have successfully transcribed a audio file with the google Speech-to-Text API from my code when I used *fetchFromUri* like this code:

```
var file = RecognitionAudio.fetchFromUri(fileUri);
var longRunningRecognizeOperation = speech.LongRunningRecognize(config, file);
```

and also when is use *fetchFromStorageUri* like this:

```
var storageFile = RecognitionAudio.fetchFromStorageUri(gsStorageUri);
var longRunningRecognizeOperation = speech.LongRunningRecognize(config, storageFile);
```

But as soon I try to use it with **fromStream**

```
var audioStream = RecognitionAudio.fromStream(fileStream);
var longRunningRecognizeOperation = speech.LongRunningRecognize(config, audioStream);
```

**I got the error**

> "The caller does not have permission"

We use a service account key json in our project but it seems that we have t o configure some permission to get `RecognitionAudio.fromStream` work.

Does anyone know what to do? :)

Comment: What are the roles set on the service account impersonated by the app? Looks like it can access the storage bucket but does not have roles to consume speech API

Answer (score 0):

The error message was misleading as it did indicate a permission issue. Instead, the error was related to the stream. However, I was able to resolve the issue by converting the stream into a ByteArray.

Like this:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    var audioByteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
    RecognitionAudio recognitionAudio = RecognitionAudio.FromBytes(audioByteArray);

    var longRunningRecognizeOperation = speech.LongRunningRecognize(googleTranscriptionConfig, recognitionAudio);
    longRunningRecognizeOperation = longRunningRecognizeOperation.PollUntilCompleted();

    var response = longRunningRecognizeOperation.Result;
    return response;
}
```